# Strange behavior of nested Angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use my directives within other directives. The following example gives so strange results that I had to give up and ask this question. I would like someone to explain me what is going on here:

```
var app = angular.module('blah', []);

app.directive('one', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<outer>one</outer>'
    };
});

app.directive('two', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<outer>two</outer>'
    };
});

app.directive('outer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
    <outer>whatever</outer>
    <one></one>
    <two></two>
    <outer>something</outer>
```

The resulting DOM is:

```
    <div ng-transclude=""></div>
    <outer></outer>
    <two></two>
    <outer>something</outer>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/WPpUL/

Is it a bug?

**EDIT:**

Expected output DOM:

```
    <div ng-transclude>whatever</div>
    <div ng-transclude>one</div>
    <div ng-transclude>two</div>
    <div ng-transclude>something</div>
```

Comment: You do get an [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:multidir?p0=one&p1=outer&p2=template&p3=%3Couter%3E)

Comment: You're right, I missed it. Still, none of the cases mentioned there seem to match this example. And how to explain different results of _one_ and _two_, as well as first and second usage of _outer_? Why they don't behave the same every time?

Comment: could you give an example of what you'd want the output to be?

Comment: Changing One and Two to use `replace: false` also resolves this.  For some reason under the combination you have angular thinks two directives are competing to apply templates and thus your error.  It appears you're not the only one puzzled by this.  The last question here is very similar to yours: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:multidir?p0=two&p1=outer&p2=template&p3=%3Couter%3E

Comment: @KayakDave Thanks, though this significantly alters the DOM, just as wrapping template with DIV or other tag. In my opinion it is a bug. Anyway, good to know I'm not alone ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `replace` we'll do it manually- this seems to keep angular happy and gets you what you need.

**1)**  Set `replace: false` instead of true in One and Two. (making angular happy)

**2)**  Manually replace the html using this link function to One and Two:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.replaceWith(element.html());
}
```

This will result in:

```
<div ng-transclude=""><b class="ng-scope">whatever</b></div>
<div ng-transclude=""><b class="ng-scope">one</b></div>
<div ng-transclude=""><b class="ng-scope">two</b></div>
<div ng-transclude=""><b class="ng-scope">something</b></div>
```

The text nodes have been surrounded by B tags to get rid of [automatically generated SPANs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/5SaF085FANw).

Here's the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/WPpUL/7/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about _element_. Well, I see it's quite a hard problem. Is there no perfect solution? :(

Comment: Looks like there is- I just updated the answer.  The final piece was doing the replace manually- which keeps Angular from complaining while getting you what you need.

Comment: And now that we do the `replaceWith()` you can use `transclude: true` or `element`.  True gets you a `span` while element uses `outer`.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work with dynamic content, for example:
`<one><p ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</p></one>`

Comment: Yea that's the tradeoff with stripping the extra dom elements.  If you need the compiled results of the template then only do step 1 above and you'll get the correct results (just with more in the dom- which angular needs).  Here's that:http://jsfiddle.net/WPpUL/8/

Comment: That's weird. Can you explain why Angular needs that extra element? I've found this: `DOCS: the root of the template always gets a new scope` So it's impossible to use a directive without creating a new scope, right?

Comment: Not all directives need a new scope.  But some, like `ng-repeat` do.  The problem is that Angular uses that 'ng-binding', that we stripped, for the $watch it uses to see if any dynamic data has changed.  It was cool to strip those when your element was static.  But without the element decorated with `ng-binding` the element loses it's two way binding.  You can see how `ng-binding` is used in the `ngBind` source code:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d7ed885984d58d344350ae267f51e8096bb6bea6/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js

Answer (score 1):

Wrap template with a root element will fix the problem

```
template: '<div><outer>one</outer></div>'
template: '<div><outer>two</outer></div>'
```

Comment: And what if I don't want to change the DOM? Why the _outer_ directive can't be a child of another directive with transclusion?